# elasticsearch python parallel_bulk can not insert data

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I use `parallel_bulk` to insert data to elasticsearch in python, but `parallel_bulk` cannot insert data. My code:

```
class CreateIndex(object):
def _gen_data(self, index, doc_type, chunk_size):
    sql = """select * from tem_search_engine_1 where rownum <= 10000"""  
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
    col_name_list = [col[0].lower() for col in self.cursor.description]
    col_name_len = len(col_name_list)
    actions = []

    start = time.time()
    for row in self.cursor:
        source = {}
        tbl_id = ""
        for i in range(col_name_len):
            source.update({col_name_list[i]: str(row[i])})
            if col_name_list[i] == "tbl_id":
                tbl_id = row[i]
        action = {
            "_index": index,
            "_type": doc_type,
            "_id": tbl_id,  
            "_source": source
        }
        actions.append(action)
        if len(actions) == chunk_size:
            print("actions time：", time.time()-start)
            yield actions
            actions = []
    print("for time：", time.time()-start)
    yield actions

def bulk_data(self, index, doc_type, chunk_size=1000, is_parallel=True, threads_counts=4):

    t1 = time.time()
    gen_action = self._gen_data(index, doc_type, chunk_size)

    if is_parallel is None or is_parallel == True:
        for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=self.es, actions=gen_action, thread_count=threads_counts):
            if not success:
                print("Insert failed: ", info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createindex = CreateIndex()
    createindex.create_index(index="se", doc_type="se_doc")
    createindex.bulk_data(index="se", doc_type="se_doc")
```

when I use `bulk_data`, but it cannot insert any data, how to deal with it?
the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/programs/ElasticSearch/CreateIndex.py", line 287, in <module>
    createindex.bulk_data(index="se", doc_type="se_doc")
  File "F:/programs/ElasticSearch/CreateIndex.py", line 179, in bulk_data
    thread_count=threads_counts, chunk_size=chunk_size):
  File "F:\programs\ElasticSearch\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 306, in parallel_bulk
    _chunk_actions(actions, chunk_size, max_chunk_bytes, client.transport.serializer)
  File "D:\anacond\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 735, in next
    raise value
  File "D:\anacond\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "D:\anacond\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 138, in _helper_reraises_exception
    raise ex
  File "D:\anacond\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 290, in _guarded_task_generation
    for i, x in enumerate(iterable):
  File "F:\programs\ElasticSearch\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 58, in _chunk_actions
    for action, data in actions:
  File "F:\programs\ElasticSearch\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 37, in expand_action
    op_type = data.pop('_op_type', 'index')
TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: sorry, could you explain better? What do you mean that you can't insert data, you run your script, and also the function bulk_data run but doesn't produce results? From your code your var is_parallel is not consistent. Could you provide a little example on how you generate it?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I have edit it. when I run this fucntion, it went error:`TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)` @Lupanoide

Comment: I can't see in you code where you use the pop method, could you provide that piece of code?

Comment: I have edit it.@Lupanoide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `parallel_bulk` method you could pass a list of dicts, or a generator,that yield a dict. Explanation [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/helpers-parallel-bulk-in-python-not-working/39498/2) . A `generator` in python serves to not load in RAM a variable, but if you should pass your `elem` in a list before - the dict `action` in the list `actions`, it has no more sense because to build a list you should load in memory all the elements inside it. In your case you are passing a generator that yield not a dict elem - `action` - but it yield the operation list - `actions`.

So, or your function _gen_data returns a list, indeed of a generator:

```
def _gen_data(self, index, doc_type, chunk_size):
    sql = """select * from tem_search_engine_1 where rownum <= 10000"""  
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
    col_name_list = [col[0].lower() for col in self.cursor.description]
    col_name_len = len(col_name_list)
    actions = []

    start = time.time()
    for row in self.cursor:
        source = {}
        tbl_id = ""
        for i in range(col_name_len):
            source.update({col_name_list[i]: str(row[i])})
            if col_name_list[i] == "tbl_id":
                tbl_id = row[i]
        action = {
            "_index": index,
            "_type": doc_type,
            "_id": tbl_id,  
            "_source": source
        }
        actions.append(action)
    return actions
```

Or you don't create the `actions` list and you yield the `action` dict:

```
def _gen_data(self, index, doc_type, chunk_size):
    sql = """select * from tem_search_engine_1 where rownum <= 10000"""  
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
    col_name_list = [col[0].lower() for col in self.cursor.description]
    col_name_len = len(col_name_list)


    start = time.time()
    for row in self.cursor:
        source = {}
        tbl_id = ""
        for i in range(col_name_len):
            source.update({col_name_list[i]: str(row[i])})
            if col_name_list[i] == "tbl_id":
                tbl_id = row[i]
        yield {
            "_index": index,
            "_type": doc_type,
            "_id": tbl_id,  
            "_source": source
        }
```

Comment: Can it yield a list and pass it to the `parallel_bulk` function like I have done?

Comment: No, and it has no sense, as I have written in my answer. Please yield the action dict, indeed